# How to hide command prompt in C

Tags: c

How can I hide the command prompt that always pops up in my C app?

From a simple ("Hello world") type of view if you don't mind.

And I wanna do it in the app I run, not from the point of view of running another app without prompt.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? The command prompt is run if you run the app from within Visual Studio.

Comment: what OS?  Isn't the command window the one where your output appears?  More details please on what you want to achieve.

Comment: The correct method for switching your compiled executable from command line to Windows mode depends on what compiler (actually, linker) you use. It could be Visual C++ (part of Visual Studio), GNU gcc either from Cygwin or MinGW, Delphi, etc.

Comment: What are you even talking about? We need example code, a description of what you're trying to do, a much more complete description of what you're seeing, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a win-32 application instead of console but don't draw a window.

Comment: Thanks. I found out how after a while.